# Render specific field collection fields in twig template

Tags: drupal, twig

I have a field collection named, "field_client_scroll" which has multiple fields, two text and an entity reference field to a media image named "field_thumbnail_client". For the text fields I can print their value using

```
{{ item.content['#field_collection_item'].field_title_client.value }}
```

I tried to use the following, but with no results

```
{{ item.content['#field_collection_item'].field_thumbnail_client.value }}
```

I would like to know what I need to use to print the image or the url to the image using the field collection field.

Comment: Did you already try to verify the content of `item.content['#field_collection_item']`, e.g `{{ dump(item.content['#field_collection_item']) }}`

Comment: Yes. Used kint to print the variables. If I change 'value' to 'target_id" it will print the id. Looking for url.

Comment: Please post the output of the `kint`

Comment: item.content array (5).
    #field_collection_item => (29). 
       values -> array (11). 
          field_thumbnail_client => array (1). 
            target_id => string (5) "39905".